# I have application on wamp but i want it on a disc so that it can run on different computer without installing wamp

Tags: php, virtual, wampserver, virtual-hosts

I am still confused on that. Is it possible? If is possible please solve  me out.

Comment: It would just about be possible but it would be very very... did I say very very fiddly to get it to work. So much so that it is not really worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an application which works well on any computer you without installing any additional software you should not use PHP which is a server side language.

However if you really need to do this, you should put php files with this application together with some library which can serve you as a http server from PHP (like React) and write a bootstrap application which:

- fires a server script
- opens a web browser with application uri

Of course using library like React will probably force you to rewrite some parts of your application.

What React exactly does:

- set up a server which listens on specified port (it may be default 80)
- created a callback for you which is fired when a request is incoming

You can then put your code to dispatch it.